# AdMob is not showing live advertisements

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I have implemented Google AdMob into my Android App, and I have used only Banner ads.

I used test ads initially to make sure the ads were working, and they were.

However, whenever I put my live ad ID's, the banner ads do not show.

I know that it can take a few days for ad placements to become live, however I had made them a week ago in advance.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Here's my Layout File code (I've blocked out the ad placement ID:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="557dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sky Q" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sky HD" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="PLACEHOLDER"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's my Main Activity code:

```
package com.jodastudios.remotecontroluniversal;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private TabItem tab1,tab2;
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tab1 = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.tab1);
        tab2 = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.tab2);

        pagerAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

                if(tab.getPosition() == 0 || tab.getPosition() == 1){
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.settings){
            // Open settings activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PreferenceActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.help){
            // Open help activity
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to show live ads in debug version without this:

documentation:

*If you want to do more rigorous testing with production-looking ads, you can now configure your device as a test device and use your own ad unit IDs that you've created in the AdMob UI. Test devices can either be added in the AdMob UI or programmatically using the Google Mobile Ads SDK.*

```
//TODO find your device id in logcat
List<String> testDeviceIds = Arrays.asList("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE231"); 
RequestConfiguration configuration =
    new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build();
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration);
```

Check this https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads